# First steps with Microsoft dynamics, can I create a full environment locally?

Tags: dynamics-crm

If I want to get started with learning MS dynamics, is it possible for me to setup a development environment on my local computer (laptop) or does it require a server to be setup?

Is this something I can get started with for free or do I need to spend $?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need Windows Server to run Dynamics CRM.

There are trials for Windows Server, SQL Server and Dynamics CRM, you can setup an environment free.

An alternative is to start a trial for Dynamics CRM Online, expect few limitations it works as CRM OnPremise.

Comment: So I would need to install this in a VM on my laptop then correct?  Or like you say use the online trial version.

Comment: yes you can use a VM, but depends on your laptop specs if it will be fast or not, online trial is easier